# MozJPEG vs Browser JPEG for blogs

Tags: wordpress, jpeg, mozjpeg

I'd like to ask about the extension which combines small size and good quality, is it .MozJPEG or Browser .JPEG? Also the one thath has no problem with whatever browser?
Thanks in advance

I am expecting to know the most practical one for a wordpress website

Comment: Are you looking for a WordPress to combine two images?

Comment: Thanks for ur interaction. Actually, I have a WordPress blog and I want to upload images with small sizes but good quality as well. I have come across a website called Squoosh.com that compresses images. they have many extensions there but I have noticed that the default one is MozJPEG. I wanted to start converting my images to it but I was afraid that maybe some browsers won't show them. That's why I asked my question.

Answer (score 1):

[MozJPEG](https://github.com/mozilla/mozjpeg) is just an improved JPEG encoder, fully compatible with the JPEG standard. So you get regular JPEG files, really, just (usually) compressed better.

A better format, which now is [supported basically everywhere](https://caniuse.com/webp), is [WebP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webp). I'd recommend using it for now.

You might also want to keep an eye on [JPEG XL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_XL), though it is [not yet supported by default by most browsers](https://caniuse.com/jpegxl).